# Android Surface and ScreenResolution

Tags: android, screen, android-canvas, surfaceview, pixel

To put some context, my game has been developped for android 1.5. So it was using the lowest resolution by default on any android phones. Which was great, game was running fast and all.

Now I added support for scoreloop which required my game to support android 1.6. When I runned the game I realized everything got smaller since I used unit dimension without looking at the screen density.

Now that I fixed sizing. I realize that my game seems a bit choppy. I believe that redrawing on the new screen resolution is the problem.

I draw my game in a Canvas in a SurfaceView. How can I make it faster? I use default functions like drawCircle, drawLine... I believe reducing the screen resolution should help since I don't need high screen resolution. I just don't know how or if it's possible.

Or may be doing my drawing in opengl would solve the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You should use the pixel format depending of your needs.

Comment: I think your confusing pixel format with pixel density. I disabled other screen size and it works like before. Thanks for the link